# JSON Nested PII data masking in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, mask, data-masking

I need to mask the following JSON data :
given JSON:

```
{  
        "key1":"value1",  
        "key2":"value2",  
        "key3": {  
            "key4":"value3"  
        }   
} 

Maksed data :
{  
       "key1":"value1",  
       "key2":"value2",  
       "key3": {  
             "key4":"000000"  
       }   
}
```

we already have a question [JSON PII data masking in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263036/json-pii-data-masking-in-java)
whoes answer works if the key is part of the main response(for example key1 , key2 or key3) , but i need something for nested values. (using jackson)

What if we have the json property name's that we need to mask but its position can differ in JSON depending on the response received. How to mask such values? 
Example : I only know that I need to mask "key4" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have the answer.  Jackson will create a `Map` for every nested property. You can use the answer from previous question and just change the process of the map

```
// Process map
if (map.containsKey("key3")) {
    Map<String, Object> nestedMap = (Map<String, Object>)map.get("key3");
    if (nestedMap.containsKey("key4")) {
        nestedMap.put("key4","000000");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently we released the first release candidate of a [high-performance JSON masker library in Java with no runtime dependencies](https://github.com/Breus/JSON-masker) which you might want to use to do this.

It works on any JSON value type (with any nesting in both JSON objects and arrays), has an extensive and configurable API, and adds minimal computation overhead both in terms of CPU time and memory allocations. Additionally, it has limited JsonPath support.

In case the masking happens in a flow where performance is critical, or you don't want to have in-house code (depending on the APIs of Jackson) for this, you might want to use this library instead.

The README should contain plenty of examples to show how to use it for your use case. Additionally, all methods part of the API are documented using JavaDoc.